# Replacing document.write()

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to replace the `document.write()` function in Javascript. Not completely sure how to do, as I don't know which element to write the HTML to.

Currently, the code javascript code is inserted to my page using:

```
<script src="//example.com/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The file contains a `document.write()` function:

```
document.write('<h2>Testing HTML</h2>Hello');
```

However, as `document.write()` can't be called asynchronously, I need to figure out another solution. I can not use `getElementsById()` or something like that, because I simply don't know any element on the target website.

I want the HTML code to be inserted exactly on the position that the script tag is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `document.write('<div id="placeholder"></div>')` and now you know an element on the website?

Comment: I don't want to use `document.write()` at all.

Comment: Why not? It's the only (reasonable) way to solve the problem.

Comment: Because, as I said in the question: "However, as `document.write()` can't be called asynchronously, I need to figure out another solution."

Comment: Why would you need to call it asynchronously? Create the placeholder, then call whatever asynchronous method you need, and then fill or replace the placeholder.

Comment: It seems your question is pretty vague.  If you know the HTML code to insert, why not just use the STYLE attribute to place it exactly where you want it?  Why does it matter if document.write() cannot be called asynchronously?  If you can't use getElementsById() because you don't know any of the elements, then I have to ask, Why not?  Is the HTML page not yours?  If it is yours, then why not just add an element with an id you can reference?

Comment: @Russ: The HTML is mine. However, I do not have control over it all the time so it might be possible that it changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script src="//example.com/file.js" type="text/javascript" id="myScript"></script>
```

And in the javascript:

```
var script = document.getElementById('myScript');
script.outerHTML += '<h2>Testing HTML</h2>Hello';
```

As you don't have the script ID, try this:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];

// Async
setTimeout(function() {
    script.outerHTML += '<h2>Testing HTML</h2>Hello';
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have the script id either.

Comment: @Robin I've edited my answer with a solution that should work without the ID.

Comment: Almost ready to choose this as the answer. Do you know if it is possible to make it run `<script>` tags? I mean the `script.outerHTML += '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Hello");</script>`? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Robin You should use `eval` in that case https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Why not have your email on the profile so people can contact you about paid jobs? Like me. ;-)

Comment: How is it possible to make this work with loading a script as well? Like, after 2 seconds, load <script src="//hello.example.com/js.js"></script>?

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to create an element to add your HTML to, if you already have your HTML in a variable, that's great, use it instead of `yourElement` below.

```
// Create an element, add HTML to it
var yourElement = document.createElement ('div');
    yourElement.innerHTML = '<div>Test</div>';
```

Then, you will get the current JavaScript tag...

```
// Get the current script tag (meaning yours)
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName ('script');
var thisScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1]
```

And you will insert your HTML element before this tag...

```
// Insert your element before current script tag
thisScript.parentNode.insertBefore (yourElement, thisScript);
```

You can also insert your HTML element after the JavaScript tag as well.

*Credit: This code was inspired by HashOver: [tildehash.com/hashover/hashover.js](http://tildehash.com/hashover/hashover.js)*